# why the value is not serial in the same input

Tags: jquery, input

I wanna increase and decrease the price function in input element.

I almost done, but I found a problem now, when I changed the price directly by keyboard, and then I cliked the arrowUp or arrowDown, the value is **not serial.**

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.input{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
i {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
<div class="wrap">
<input class="input" type="text" value='1' />
<i class="plus">+</i>
<i class="minus">-</i>
</div>
```

```
var input = $('.input'),
val = parseFloat($('.input').val()),
plus = $('.plus'),
minus = $('.minus');

    plus.on('mousedown', function(){
        input.val(++val);
        if(val > 10) { alert('hi'); }
    });
    minus.on('mousedown', function(){
        input.val(--val);
        if(val > 10) { alert('hi'); }
    });
    input.on('change', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.val() > 10) { alert('hi'); }
    })
```

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/weFdj)

Comment: What do you mean by "*is serial*"?

Comment: if I enter 2, then click plus, the value will become other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your JavaScript.

```
input.on("keyup", function(){
  val = Number(input.val());
});
```

Your variable is only updated by pressing the buttons, but you also want it to be updated when the user changes the value.

### [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/cerkh)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you get the origin number when the first page is loaded. 
you should get from event call.

Just put `val = parseFloat($('.input').val())` into the call back `plus.on('mousedown', function(){...}`

Checkout the JS fiddle here.
http://jsfiddle.net/WJakG/1/